What's that late '00s or '10s horror movie with a huge mirror in an old-style bathroom that's two-way
Can't remember the details of this movie, and frankly I might be mixing up two different movies.
The main chick is getting more and more freaked out by this very old building she works in - think it's somewhere in Europe like a chateau that was used decades earlier to take care of sick people (kids? Maybe an orphanage?). As the movie progresses more crazy stuff happens to the lady.
There's one scene I recall where she's in the bathroom freaking out and she realizes she smashes this huge mirror that's there. Turns out that the mirror is actually covering some room on the other side. As she investigates further I think she eventually finds an elevator that goes down deep under ground where there's people wearing gas masks or something. It's like it flips between the way it looked when it was in use decades earlier, and modern day down in that basement place..

If you're mixing up two movies, one of them might be Silent Hill. In particular your last couple of sentences (elevator, gas masks, and flipping between two periods) match closely.

@lemoviesearchinglike well take note, the answer is below.

It's the 2004 horror film Saint Ange (AKA House of Voices).

In 1958, Anna Jurin, a young cleaning woman, is sent to spruce up the abandoned St. Ange orphanage in the French Alps region. In fact, she has been sent there because she is pregnant, but she keeps this a secret from others. [...] As she begins her cleaning duties, Anna begins to experience strange things such as hearing the footsteps and voices of children down the hallways. [...] As time passes, Anna begins to suspect that St. Ange holds a dark secret.

It contains all the scenes you've described. The one with the mirror with the rooms and dumbwaiter behind it is near the end IIRC. Here's the trailer:



